# NoraUI - feature regression while changing data provider

Tags: noraui

Whenever I change my data provider (from Gherkin to Excel) my features go back to an older version.

Is that an expected behavior ?

How can I overcome this ?

Answer (score 0):

When you use Excel data provider, each run (of robot) copy all data from your Excel file in your feature file.

If you want put all data directly in you feature file, you need choose Gherkin data provider and put all your data directly in you feature file.